# how do you generate an ordered linear combination of values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, concatenation

I have a dictionary set up like so:

```py
d1 = {1:['A'],2:['B'],3:['C','D'],4:['E','F'],5:['G'],6:['A']}
```

I need to concatenate all of the linear combinations of the values from this dictionary. However, the order of the letter in each list is important: concatenated strings should only be generated for those which are in the same order, ie, 'C' and 'E' should be concatenated, not 'D' and 'E'. For example, the results using the dictionary above should look like:

```
String 1 = 'ABCEGA'

String 2 = 'ABDFGA'
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Why is this a dictionary where the keys are increasing integers, and not just a list? `[['A'],['B'],['C','D'],...]` would seem to represent the same information more simply (and would be simpler to deal with for  your problem).

Comment: It seems like concatenating `A` with `D` breaks the rule — `A` is not in the "same order" as `D` in the same sense that `C` is not in the same order as `F`. What should happen with a dict like `d1 = {1:['A'], 2:['B', 'C'], 3:['D','E','F']}`?

Comment: By order I just meant placement/location in the list: so 'A' is in the first position and so is 'B' and 'D'

Comment: But 'D' is second.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. Yes you are right, the previous comment I made is 'misleading' (on the way to wrong territory but not quite there yet...). Im sure there is proper vocabulary for this, but all of the values with a single item are to be added to all concatenated strings, whereas position information is needed only for values with more than one item. These locations with more than one item are positions of variability whereas the other locations represent uniformity, and I merely needed all possible linear strings in order to describe/characterize this variability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

z = list(map(list,(zip_longest(*d1.values()))))
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'A'], [None, None, 'D', 'F', None, None]]

for ix_i, i in enumerate(z):
    for ix_j, j in enumerate(i):
        if not j:
            z[ix_i][ix_j] = z[ix_i-1][ix_j]

list(map(''.join, z))
# ['ABCEGA', 'ABDFGA']
```

---

A rather obscurer [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) based approach:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, accumulate

z = zip_longest(*d1.values())
out = [[*accumulate(i, lambda x, y: y or x)] for i in zip(*z)]
list(map(''.join, zip(*out)))
# ['ABCEGA', 'ABDFGA']
```

Comment: Wow. Nice and succinct. Much appreciated!